# Label move the position on its own

Tags: vb.net, label

This is maybe stupid, but I seriously don't know why it does this:

[image]

As you can see in the gif, the first proxy is normally placed, but all other proxies went to new line.

I am importing proxies like this:

```
Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog With {.Filter = "Text Files (.txt)|*.txt"}
If ofd.ShowDialog = vbOK Then
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName)
    proxies = sr.ReadToEnd
    list = proxies.Split(Environment.NewLine)
End If
```

In timer I have this:

```
Label6.Text = list(ProxyIndex)
UseProxy(list(ProxyIndex))
'here is where I am navigating to the website'
ProxyIndex += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Fixed):

```
Label6.Text = list(ProxyIndex).Trim
```

If that does not works, then try this else:

```
Label6.Text = list(ProxyIndex.replace(Environment.NewLine, string.empty))
```

Comment: I fixed it with this: `Label6.Text = list(ProxyIndex).Trim` Thank you!

Comment: my fault I've written it on the fly, of course it was an index of an array so can't be trimmed. I'm glad to be of help.